# How to add instance variables or properties to an XCTestCase?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, properties, header-files, xctest

I just learned, that I must declare instance variables and properties in a *header file* in Objective-C. So now i want to add instance variables to my `XCTestCase` subclass — but it turns out, XCTestCases come without header files.
How do i declare instance variables in my test cases?

Comment: As answered below you can declare properties and ivars in a class extension. Make sure you look into apple's documentation for the difference between an instance variable and a property as well.

Comment: The answer is - don't use instance variables, use properties.

Comment: @JuJoDi But my question applies equally to instance variables and properties — it’s about where they can/have to be declared, not if either of the two should be preferred?

Comment: @MartinW Edited the title to reflect your comment.

Comment: @JuJoDi That’s better. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to declare them in the header file at all.  Instance variables and properties are commonly added within a private category in the implementation file:

```
@interface MyClass () {
    BOOL _someVar;
}

@property NSString *someOtherVar;

- (void)_aPrivateMethod:(id)something;

@end

@implementation MyClass
...
@end
```

Comment: Can i add instance variables to `@interface MyClass : XCTestCase {…}` directly, or do i have to add a second `@interface MyClass () {…}` below to add them? I tried and both variants seem to work…

Comment: Yes both will work.  The method I outline in my answer keeps the instance variable/properties completely private, however, as no other class has visibility of them.